# ASP.Net 5 (beta 8) custom method in AccountController throws ObjectDisposedException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to implement some custom auth logic. In the `AccountController` I wrote a method:

```
public async void ULogin()
{
    EnsureDatabaseCreated(_applicationDbContext);

    var token = Request.Form["token"];
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string query = Request.Scheme + "://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=" + "" + token + "" + "&host=" + "" + Request.Host;
    string res = await client.GetStringAsync(query);

    dynamic resObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res);
    string _displayName = resObj.first_name + resObj.last_name;
    string _uLoginIdentity = resObj.identity;

    var user = _userManager.Users.Where(u => u.ULoginIdentity == _uLoginIdentity).FirstOrDefault();
    //etc
}
```

While running the last line the `System.ObjectDisposedException` appears. I also find out that Model and ChangeTracker properties of `ApplicationDbContext` throw `ObjectDisposedException`. Other methods in the controller work fine. I didn't change the controller's ctor or Startup. What might be the problem?

Comment: Please consider answering your own question and flagging it as "answered" tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I should define the method as `public async Task ULogin()`